# Correct way to use Date format in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

i have a Laravel project with Postgres database. I have some problems with date format.

This is a piece of input field in Laravel blade

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
     <label for="nome" class="required">
       Birth Date
     </label>
     <input class="form-control date" type="text"value="{{ (!empty($patient) && $patient->datebirth) ? 
     Carbon\Carbon::parse($patient->datebirth)->format('d/m/Y') : '' }}"  name="datebirth" 
     id="datebirth" />
</div>
```

And this is the script that activate the bootstrap date field

```php
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.date').datepicker({
        firstDayOfWeek: 1, // The first day of week is Monday
        weekDayFormat: 'narrow', // Only first letter for the weekday names
        inputFormat: 'd/M/y',
        outputFormat: 'd/M/y',
        titleFormat: 'EEEE d MMMM y',
        markup: 'bootstrap4',
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        modal: false
    });
});
```

This is the controller code

```php
public function save(Request $req){
    $validatedData  = $req->validate([
        'name' => ['required', 'max:255'],
        'datebirth' => ['required','date'],
    ]);

   $newPatient = new Patient;
   $newPatient->name = $req->name;
   $newPatient->datebirth = $req->datebirth;
   $newPatient->save();
}
```

But when i save the object the error is:

```
SQLSTATE[22008]: Datetime field overflow: 7 ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "22/04/1985"...
```

Because the database want y m d format, but i want to use in my views d/M/y. I i change the outputFormat: in 'y/M/d' the save operation works, but when the user changes the date using the widget (input field), it is shown in the format y/M/d.

in the controller I simply take the value of the datebirth field of the request, i assign it to the object and save it. I would like to avoid doing format conversions in the controller every time I save / edit the object

What is the right way to manage this situation?

is there any way to avoid converting the data format every time before saving?

Comment: Share the code where you're actually trying to save this value to the database. You likely just need to take the input `22/04/1985` and format it to a valid date  `1985-04-22` or datetime `1985-04-22 00:00:00` before saving it.

Comment: Sidenote: If you're allowing the User to pick their format on the front-end, this statement is unavoidable: *"I would like to avoid doing format conversions in the controller every time I save / edit the object"*. Gotta pick one or the other.

Comment: I've updated the post. No, the user can't pick the format, he can only change the value of the datebirth field. Example:  change to 22/04/1985 to 25/04/1985.  The format of the UI is always d/M/y.

Comment: Oh, sorry, must have misread that. But still, you're gonna have to do some format swapping, to `d/m/Y` on the front-end, then `Y-m-d` on the backend. It kinda looks like you're doing that now, so I'm not sure why it would be displaying in the wrong format on the frontend.

Answer (score 2):

A [date input expects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) the `value` attribute to contain data in ISO 8601 `YYYY-mm-dd` format. Since you are requesting a date, using this input type is the right way to do the form. Carbon will by default convert to ISO 8601 when echoed as a string.

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="nome" class="required">
        Birth Date
    </label>
    <input
        type="date"
        class="form-control"
        value="{{ ($patient->datebirth ?? false) ? $patient->datebirth->toDateString() : '' }}"
        name="datebirth" 
        id="datebirth"
    />
</div>
```

The input will be sent to the server in ISO 8601 format when the request is made. But Laravel will automatically handle the formatting during save, if you set up your model correctly. E.g.

```php
class Patient extends Model
{
    protected $dates = [
        "datebirth",
    ];
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but doing so, when i open the page, the input field have this date format "1985-04-22 00:00:00", when the user change the date (for example change the day) it's shows 1985/04/21.

Comment: You should get rid of the Javascript date picker and use the browser's. If the column is DATETIME instead of DATE its string representation would include the time, but the browser shouldn't show it for a date type input. Anyway, I'll update the answer for that. To be clear, this uses the client's browser locale to determine display format for the date input. Forcing a user to comply with your date format is just unnecessary friction.

Comment: using Javascript widget for date the user has a component with greater functions, more pleasant and above all it is homogeneous on the various browsers.Safari does not have a standard component for handling date type inputs.User is not asked to respect the format, he selects the date using the widget.I would like to try to find the correct input/output configuration of the JavaScript component and the one to use in the input value of the.blade view, and possibly of the model,so that the format conversions take place automatically between the data reading,rendering and writing phases.

Comment: You have inputFormat and outputFormat in your datepicker settings that is the place to set format for user and format for DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert Date **from DD/MM/YYYY format to YYYY/MM/DD**(that follow by database date datatype as well as timestamp datatype)

```
$date = $request->deal_date; //we got DD/MM/YYYY format date from form post data
$deal_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

then you can **modify the Laravel Request array** data before pass that array data to database

```
$request->merge([
     'deal_date' => $deal_date,
]);
```

Or You want to add any field in Request then you can like this

```
$request->request->add(['user_id' => $user_id]);
```

Or You want to remove any field from request then you can also do like this

```
$request->request->remove('store_idname');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem using mutators:

```
public function setBirthDateAttribute($value)
    {
        if( $value ){
            $data = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value)->format('Y-m-d');
            $this->attributes['birthDate'] = $data;
        }
    }
```